# Can you only embed a URL in a QR code, or can you embed any content?

Tags: qr-code

Is it possible to embed any content into a QR code, or is it restricted only to URLs?

Comment: http://imgur.com/SccQ2zy ;)

Answer (score 0):

No necessarily. Although QR codes are most likely to contain URLs it is not limited to that.

It has been used for encryption purposes (http://qrworld.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/encrypted-qr-codes/), website login (https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm), as well as for storage for banking information (http://www.bpay.com.au/Business/Large-Business/Industry-Insights/Industry-Insights/QR-codes-go-live-in-mobile-banking.aspx).

If you were looking to embed an image or video content it would be best to have it link to those respective URLs.